# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a website that has been up and running for several months.  In it, there is a model called Project.  I recently added a boolean DB field to the projects table called "expired" and it's default is set to false.  Now when trying to create a project i get the following error in production only:

```
NilClass#create (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError) "unknown attribute: expired"
```

i thought this meant that the db field does not exist, but I checked the console and the "expired" attribute is there.  The error happens at this line in the projects controller:

```
@project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
```

and here are the project_params:

```
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :location, :budget, :description, 
                                    :time_frame, {:tag_list => []}, 
                                    questions_attributes: [:content, :id, :_destroy])
end
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error.  In general, I only want to deal with projects that are not expired, so I have the following in the model:

```
default_scope { where(expired: false) }
```

I'm not sure why that would cause the error though.  I also need the default scope to have expired be false so I can't take that line out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am just wondering on `NilClass#create`. Why on earth thats gonna throw that exception. Logically this means the current_user is nil. But the exception says something from projects models. On nil projects can't be called at least!! Anyways, not trying to give any answer right now. Just shared whats going on in my mind.

`@project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)`

Comment: Because the problem only happens on production, may I ask if you have run `$ rake db:migrate` on your production server so the new column is also added to your production database?